# when working with nodejs and rabbitMQ, how do we nack before the default rabbit time out?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, timeout, puppeteer

I am working with Rabbit MQ & seeming to have rabbitmq 406 error that time out has been reached and the connection is closed because the connection is closing before i finish processing my data & sending an "ack" back

`Uncaught Error Error: Channel closed by server: 406 (PRECONDITION-FAILED) with message "PRECONDITION_FAILED - delivery acknowledgement on channel 1 timed out. Timeout value used: 1800000 ms. This timeout value can be configured, see consumers doc guide to learn more" at <anonymous> (c:\tru\truendo2\trucrawler\node_modules\amqplib\lib\channel.js:421:17) at mainAccept (c:\tru\truendo2\trucrawler\node_modules\amqplib\lib\connection.js:63:33) at go (c:\tru\truendo2\trucrawler\node_modules\amqplib\lib\connection.js:486:48) at emit (events:513:28) at emitReadable_ (internal/streams/readable:590:12) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues:81:21) --- TickObject --- at init (internal/inspector_async_hook:25:19) at emitInitNative (internal/async_hooks:202:43) at emitInitScript (internal/async_hooks:505:3) at nextTick (internal/process/task_queues:132:5) at emitReadable (internal/streams/readable:582:13) at addChunk (internal/streams/readable:334:7) at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable:297:9) at Readable.push (internal/streams/readable:234:10) at onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) at callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks:130:17)`your text``

I changed the default "consumer_timeout" in the config file and it did not make a difference, node did turning off consumer_timeout in the advanced.config file.

Comment: By any chance were you able solve this?